# Upgraded to Chrome 61.0.3163 via ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't launch because NSS out of date

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I upgraded to Chrome 61.0.3163 via ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't launch because NSS out of date. Launching Chrome in terminal gives:

```
NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
```

Running

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

gives

```
libnss3 is already the newest version (2:3.21-1ubuntu4)
```

Should I try to get a newer version of libnss that's not in the repository? I downgraded my version of Chrome for now.

Edit:

```
apt-cache policy libnss3
libnss3:
  Installed: 2:3.21-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2:3.21-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.21-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: What do you mean "Chrome PPA"?  There's no official Chrome PPA that I'm aware of, other than Google's primary repository they use for distributing their software.

Comment: I meant the Google repository: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: Downloading directly from the website gives the same version, same problem.

Comment: Do me a favor, run `sudo apt-get update`, then attach the output of `apt-cache policy libnss3` to your question as an edit.  Also include the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, please.  My guess is you do *not* have the `xenial-security` or `xenial-updates` repository enabled and then your software on your computer updated to latest versions properly, as the latest `libnss3` actually available for Xenial is 3.28, in the `xenial-security` and `xenial-updates` repository.

Comment: @ThomasWard you're right, neither `-security` nor `-updates` is enabled for anything.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes. You are right. Why is everything commented out? It might have been this way since I installed it.

Comment: I am having the same issue using Ubuntu 15.10. But in my list i have wily-security and wily-updates but they are not commented. Any help ?

Comment: @cosmincalistru Your problem is different. You are using an Ubuntu release that is no longer supported. See [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815) and [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades). Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf is [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and its repositories [have been moved over](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) to the old-releases server. Please upgrade. It is dangerous to keep using EoL releases, because they no longer receive updates for security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your computer is not running with the `xenial-updates` or `xenial-security` repositories enabled.

Enable the repositories (uncomment the lines for those repositories), and then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and upgrade all your packages to the latest package versions.

Answer (score 4):

Your version of libnss3 seems to be broken or missing.
Try reinstalling it

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

Comment: Only works if they enable `xenial-updates` or `xenial-security` because it needs a newer version than `libnss3` that was in Xenial's standard repos (and that repo never gets updates, it's `-updates` and `-security` which contain the updates and updated `libnss3`, and those're usually critically-needed repos)