# Installed Chrome but not opening

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed Chrome from the google website for Ubuntu 64 bit.  However, when I go to launch it from the shortcut in the Application Manager it will not open.

When I try to open it from the command line I get the following:

```
mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ google-chrome
[17943:17978:0915/102720.885730:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)]
NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required.
Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)

mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ google-chrome-stable
[17982:18017:0915/102735.683053:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)]
NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required.
Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Ok just tried the following:

```
mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall libnss3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,133 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main libnss3 amd64 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2 [1,133 kB]
Fetched 1,133 kB in 0s (1,501 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 1182050 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnss3_2%3a3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnss3:amd64 (2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2) over (2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2) ...
Setting up libnss3:amd64 (2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
N: Ignoring file 'unifi_sysvinit_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'unifi_sysvinit_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'unifi_sysvinit_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ google-chrome
[19519:19554:0915/111546.104207:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)]
NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required.
Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: {mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ google-chrome
[17943:17978:0915/102720.885730:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
mblanco@mblanco-MS-7680:~$ google-chrome-stable
[17982:18017:0915/102735.683053:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)}

Comment: Not sure if the {} worked exactly how it was suppose to there.

Comment: Ok So I just edit my post, and don't comment?

Comment: Exactly! :) Please add your Ubuntu version to your question, e.g. „Ubuntu 16.04“.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install --reinstall libnss3` and try `google-chrome` again.

Comment: Man I am sorry I am trying to use the {} button but I keep messing up the formatting.  I am completely new to this forum.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer below is right: Your current Ubuntu version doesn't support the current Chrome. Only thing you can do is upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (or 17.04, or downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, but I wouldn't recommend this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgraded to Chrome 61.0.3163 via ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't launch because NSS out of date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953460/upgraded-to-chrome-61-0-3163-via-ppa-on-ubuntu-16-04-but-it-wont-launch-because)

Answer (score 2):

Do you use an old version of Ubuntu?

Upgrading to the latest Ubuntu (LTS recommended) version will solve your problem. Check this out [Can't launch Chrome on ubuntu 15.10](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss/+question/657762)

Comment: Thanks for the help, which version should I upgrade to from 15.04?  I just use it for the basics and mostly from the GUI.

Comment: I prefer using [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) (Long Term Support), which are being supported for years. I recommend upgading to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. When you upgrade,  tell me if you had any success.

Comment: I went to this site to follow to do the upgrade: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts  However when I type do-release-upgrade it tells me no new release found

Comment: I recommend burning a Live CD or make a bootable Live USB with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and choose Upgrade. Check this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB7SV.png)