# Google chrome wont launch (Out of date nss)

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, security

I'm unable to launch google-chrome-stable. This is the error I am getting:

```
[4604:4640:0929/093415.646539:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

People suggest if you are running an older version of ubuntu it won't work but I am on 16.04

I have been looking online and have tried all the different suggestions e.g.
to perform security updates.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

However if I run `$ apt-cache policy libnss3` I get the following:

```
libnss3:
  Installed: 2:3.21-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2:3.21-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.21-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

EDIT

After running `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`
output related to google chrome:

```
Ign:19 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease             
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:21 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Fetched 102 kB in 7s (13.9 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key E1254F21D636B7EFDE41D2AF50E2BCF0E3805CD8 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  google-chrome-stable
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/65.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 403416 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_61.0.3163.100-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (61.0.3163.100-1) over (61.0.3163.79-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (61.0.3163.100-1) ...
```

I am still seeing the same error message after this after a restart

Comment: I would suggest Google Chrome itself needs updating. How did you install it?

Comment: @MichaelBay I downloaded the deb package from here https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/ and installed using `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: OK, does `sudo apt update` (yes, in any 16,04+ use `apt` instead of `apt-get` and `full-upgrade` instead of `dist-upgrade`) produce any error? Please try running again `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, [edit] and post the full error messages, if any.

Comment: It shouldn't need a restart (but try it anyway).

Comment: @MichaelBay No still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgraded to Chrome 61.0.3163 via ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't launch because NSS out of date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953460/upgraded-to-chrome-61-0-3163-via-ppa-on-ubuntu-16-04-but-it-wont-launch-because)

Answer (score 3):

just try below commands on your ubuntu machine.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3
```

It will fix your issue with libnss3 package